# How to prove line bundle L is trivial if and only if its dual bundle us trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

How to prove line bundle L is trivial if and only if its dual bundle us trivial ?

Answer (score 2):

The double dual of $L$ is isomorphic to $L$.  So since the dual of the trivial bundle is trivial, we are done.

My first thought was that in the Picard group, the dual of a line bundle is it's inverse, so if the inverse of $L$ is the identity, it is pretty clear that $L$ is the identity.